# Get Travis CI to ignore an external library?

Tags: travis-ci

I added the dropboxChooserSDK library to my project as an external module. Now Travis is trying to build the library and it fails.

Is there a way to ignore the library?

My project structure looks like this:

- app
- build
- *dropboxChooserSDK*
- gradle

Error from Travis:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

**What went wrong:**

- A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
- A problem occurred configuring project ':dropboxChooserSDK'.
  failed to find Build Tools revision 19.1.0